# Por que um StackOverflow em português?

Tags: debate

Se no geral o mundo da tecnologia é baseado na lingua inglesa, qual o sentido de começarmos a fragmentar isso? Não é bom para ninguém!  Imagina se de repente todos os franceses, japoneses, chineses, alemães, italianos começassem a usar o Stackoverflow de usas próprias linguas!  Isso defazaria as pesquisas no google que todos fazemos.  Em suma, isso não é nada bom na minha opinião. O que acham?

Comment: Qual a porcentagem de pessoas que são proficientes em leitura e **escrita** em Inglês?

Comment: Ironicamente você se esqueceu de pesquisar sobre o assunto em inglês antes de postar sua pergunta. Existem diversas discussões sobre isso em http://meta.stackoverflow.com. Por exemplo, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194959

Comment: Qual a porcentagem de pessoas que não são proeficientes? Cara... acho que para quem trabalha nessa área, saber o mínimo é praticamento obrigatório

Comment: @Kaue Saber o mínimo é uma coisa. Brasileiro sempre acha que consegue "enganar" em outro idioma. Você trabalha em equipe? Peça para o estagiário expor um problema não trivial relacionado à arquitetura de um sistema num fórum em Inglês como o SO.

Comment: Calma pessoal... não estou querendo denunciar o pt-br...  É só um debate que acho que vale a pena!

Comment: @Kaue isso já foi debatido e foi decidido que vale à pena ter esse site. Acho que você deveria refletir se faz sentido o que você afirmou sobre pesquisas e como é elitista o pensamento que tecnologia só deve ser discutida em inglês. Mas de qualquer forma desejo boa sorte à você na sua jornada de ir em todos os sites de tecnologia em português, ou quem sabe de todas as outras línguas diferentes do inglês, dizendo para eles fecharem porque não é bom para ninguém que eles existam.

Comment: @bigown, claramente você é um polemista que não está de mente aberta para discussões. Em qual momento eu disse que não é bom para ninguém? Estabeleci que na minha opinião é negativo, mas em momento nenhum falei que era totalmente ruim! E nunca disse que tecnologia só deveria ser debatida em inglês. Tire essa bitola ufanista que você tem e admita que inglês é a lingua em que pessoas de diferentes nações se comunicam! Não é a toa que inglês é "ensinado" nas escolas públicas!

Comment: @Kaue na sua segunda frase: "Não é bom para ninguém!". E lendo esse seu comentário agora eu vi quem só está enxergando o que quer. Portanto não há mais o que dizer sobre isso.

Comment: Não acho que esta pergunta deva ser fechada, é uma discussão válida – embora aqui a chance de você encontrar pessoas que sejam contra o site seja bem baixa. É como entrar numa churrascaria e tentar defender a alimentação vegana.

Comment: Muita gente usa o StackOverflow em inglês vindo pelo Google, mas nunca fez uma pergunta ou respondeu porque não se sente confortável escrevendo em outro idioma. O StackOverflow em português veio para solucionar isso, para permitir que qualquer pessoa que fale nosso idioma possa perguntar, responder, comentar sem ficar pensando se a preposição está correta, se o verbo é adequado, se o adjetivo faz sentido, etc. Afinal aqui somos todos fluentes na nossa língua. É claro que a pergunta precisa fazer sentido e estar dentro do contexto de programação.

Comment: Eu mesmo adorei a idéia de um site desse tipo em português, já tive vários problemas em projetos pessoais e acabei não achando nada em inglês e como ainda estou graduando, não tenho domínio do idioma, o que dificulta postar em sites gringos, mesmo usando tradutor, alias, alguém já tentou traduzir uma pergunta técnica no tradutor? Quase uma missão impossível.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Essa medida pode ter sido pensada para facilitar quem não sabe como pesquisar ou, até mesmo, quem não tem um conhecimento muito bom em inglês.

Acho que, quem realmente é ativo no Stack Overflow, vai responder tanto em português quanto em inglês, para ambos os públicos alvo, não prejudicando o Stack em inglês, que muitas vezes vai ser usado até como fonte dessa versão portuguesa.

Comment: Sim, não é por isso que as pessoas vão parar de pesquisar no stack(en).
Mudei minha opinião parcialmente ao ler o indicado em comentário abaixo
[link]( http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/ola-mundo-announcing-stack-overflow-in-portuguese/ )

Answer (score 9):

O "mundo da tecnologia" será fragmentado, sim, entretanto muitas pessoas atualmente **excluídas** desse mundo **passarão a fazer parte dele!** Eu vejo a Informática como uma ferramenta poderosa de **ascensão social** e econômica, e o StackOverflow um aliado poderoso no desenvolvimento pessoal de quem mexe com Informática. Não é ao "mundo da tecnologia" que quero ajudar, e sim a quem quer entrar nele mas [ainda] não consegue...

Se hoje a informática está "dominada" pela língua inglesa, isso é uma característica histórica da nossa época, nada mais. Os Americanos levaram a Computação pra frente primeiro, então é natural que a maior parte do conhecimento nessa área esteja em inglês. Mas o conhecimento se dissemina! Não faz sentido "prender" o conhecimento somente para que uma comunidade não seja fragmentada, não se não resolvermos primeiro o problema dos excluídos dessa comunidade.

E sobre "franceses, japoneses, chineses, alemães, italianos" etc, você acha que isso já não acontece? Eu tenho muita curiosidade de saber o que se existe na internet em coreano, já que a Coréia do Sul é o país com a maior comunidade digital do mundo! E os japoneses, com toda aquela "cultura da robótica"? O fato é que eu não tenho sequer *ideia* da quantidade de conteúdo interessante que existe nessas línguas (e outras) - já que eu não as entendo. Pode ser até que exista por lá algo tão ou mais interessante que o StackOverflow, e nós só nunca ouvimos falar nisso por falta de interesse deles em "exportar"... Improvável, mas quem sabe?

Aprender outra língua é difícil. Aprender informática é difícil. Será mesmo que temos que impor **duas** dificuldades a quem se interessa pelo assunto, quando uma só já dá bastante trabalho pra superar? Eventualmente um certo contato com a língua inglesa será necessário, nem que seja pra aprender uns termos técnicos, mas eu vejo um mundo onde não se espera mais de um programador que ele saiba inglês do que de um advogado que ele saiba latim...

Comment: Brilhante resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Na minha opinião, estar em português facilita o acesso ao conteúdo para um grande número de pessoas do nosso país, que hoje tem dificuldades de iniciar a programação por não ter conhecimento do inglês ou possuir um conhecimento básico, as vezes apenas técnico.

Tende ser a favorável, pois quanto mais pessoas estiverem interessadas no assunto, maior será o poder tecnológico do nosso país.

Answer (score 2):

Os dois são comunidades diferentes como já fora explicado, e não há disputa, as pessoas podem fazer uso de um, de outro ou ambos, basta decidir qual comunidade deixa a pessoa mais a vontade.

É muito mais fácil questionar/explicar algo em sua língua nativa (considerando que ainda assim ainda surgem problemas de interpretação).
Isso sem contar que todos sabemos da rotina de quem é desenvolvedor, ter que criar uma pergunta boa em inglês e ficar traduzindo respostas pra chegar a um novo entendimento é apenas mais um problema pro cara que a princípio já tinha um problema com o código.